# How to prevent Java from converting barcode to scientific notation

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm trying to read a barcode from a csv file. The curious thing is that, when I open the file in IntelliJ, it shows the barcode in full. When I try reading the csv file, the barcode is converted to a number in scientific notation.

The most common solution I have found online was to convert the String to a Double using Double.parseDouble(string). But this throws an exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5,40014E+12"
```

The actual method:

```
public String getField(String barcode) {
    String field = null;
    try {
        String line;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] barcodeData = line.split(delimiter);
            System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(barcodeData[2]));
            if (barcodeData[2].equals(barcode)) {
                field = barcodeData[67];
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return field;
}
```

This method is used in a test where there is a hardcoded expected result. But field always returns null in this case, since the if clause will never return true here. The actual exception is thrown in the System.out.println where I check how the number is read from the CSV.

The barcode should be: 5400141331875

What is actually read from the csv file: 5,40014E+12

How do I stop Java from converting the barcode to the scientific notation?

**EDIT**

I've found a "solution". If I don't open the actual CSV file, the numbers are not converted to the scientific notation. For me this is an actual solution, I hope someone that has the same issue as me in the future finds the actual answer why my barcodes were unable to be converted from String to Double/Long. Thank you all for you help.

Comment: You are sure that value `...E+12` is not because of `CSV`?

Comment: You must to use a `Long` when you write into CSV

Comment: Barcode data is actually a string, not a number. You should treat it as a string. If you get scientific notation, the problem happens before your program is involved.

Comment: What is the content of the CSV if you open it with a text editor?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parsing it to Long instead of Double ?
Please see below, I get the value as expected :

```
String s = "5400141331875";
System.out.println(Double.valueOf(s).longValue());
```

prints 5400141331875

Comment: This is not an answer. It is a comment

Comment: @Gauravsa I was a bit quick..Answer updated with proposal

Comment: The String that needs to be converted is "5,40014E+12", because that's what is read from the CSV file, eventhough in the CSV the content is "5400141331875". And parsing to Long throws the same exception.

Comment: @Audiosleef No it doesn't. Try replacing your line `System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(barcodeData[2]));` with `System.out.println(Double.valueOf(barcodeData[2]).longValue());` and see what you get

Comment: @funkyjelly Throws: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5,40014E+12"

Comment: @Audiosleef For me the below works just fine. I don't know what you're actually doing wrong
        `String[] myar = {"1","2","5400141331875"};
        System.out.println(Double.valueOf(myar[2]).longValue());`
this prints 5400141331875 without exceptions

Comment: @Audiosleef You can also try using `Long.parseLong(barcodeData[2]);`

Comment: You could even do `System.out.println(myar[2])` and get the same result.

Comment: @Henry Agreed, the point is whether the OP would need to subsequently treat this as Long or String. My code above was just to exhibit a solution

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution but not for csv files
You need to convert the cell in csv file to a numeric value

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
  case NUMERIC:
    String value = new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following:

```
  BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("5400141331875");

  System.out.println(bd.longValue());  // this prints 5400141331875
```

Comment: The OP wanted to avoid the conversion to scientific notation

Comment: Throws: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Character , is neither a decimal digit number, decimal point, nor "e" notation exponential mark.